# Shiny app with password

Tags: r, passwords, shiny

I have a question about running shiny app after username and password are correct. Similar question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28987622/starting-shiny-app-after-password-input) but I wont to run my whole app.R from `runApp(appDir =())`Is is possible at all ? I hope this is not the same question as in the link. I finished my app and I want to only add username and password for protection. 
Thanks!

Comment: It seems to me you want a Password App that upon activation (username and password = TRUE) will start another app?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Your solution is great and I'm wondering if there is possible to insted:   ` if (USER$Logged == TRUE) 
    {
      output$page <- renderUI({
        div(class="outer",do.call(navbarPage,c(inverse=TRUE,title = "Contratulations you got in!",ui2())))
      })
      print(ui)`
 I can run my app.R ?

Comment: Its hard to understand for what it needed? but you can for example create `cmd` which `runapp` .. after `login`run cmd and then redirect to new adress. But it cant be done for many users simulteneosly(my mind). do you want app which runs more than one time when more than one users `logged`  ?

Comment: I have Shiny Server open source app and I wont to add logging window. If username and password are TRUE somebody can see my app.