# How to create a login page in shiny?

Tags: r, shiny

The goal is to have a shiny module `ui1.R` that loads a second module `ui2.R` when the button `confirm` is clicked. I think the issue is that `is.null(input$confirm)` is always invalidated. What I need instead, is to invalidate the expression only once `confirm` is clicked.
The question is very close to [Starting Shiny app after password input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28987622/starting-shiny-app-after-password-input), but I am trying to modularize the solution.

**ui.R**

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)
htmlOutput("page")
```

**server.R**

```
rm(list = ls())
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(shinyjs)
Logged <-  FALSE

shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  source('ui1.R') #login page
  source('ui2.R')


  observeEvent(!is.null(input$confirm), {
    Logged <<- T
  })

  observe({
    if (Logged == FALSE) {
      output$page <- renderUI({ 
        ui1Output('ui1Output') 
      })
      output$lsuId <- renderText({ input$lsuId })
    }
    if (Logged == TRUE) 
    {
      output$page <- renderUI({ ui2 })
    }
  })
  callModule(ui1,'ui1') 
})
```

**ui1.R**

```
library(shinyjs)

ui1Output <-  function(id, label = "ui1") {
  ns <- NS(id)
  shinyUI(fluidPage(
    useShinyjs(),
    titlePanel("Form"),
    div(textInput(ns("lsuId"), "This has to be filled", ""),
      actionButton(ns("confirm"), "Submit", class = "btn-primary")
    )
  ))
}

ui1 <- function(input, output, session) {
  observe({
    LSUID <- reactive({ input$lsuId })
    shinyjs::toggleState(id = "confirm", condition = LSUID())
  })
}
```

**ui2.R**

```
ui2<-  shinyUI(fluidPage(
 div("well done!")
))
```

**global.R**

```
source('ui1.R') #login page
source('ui2.R')
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Starting Shiny app after password input](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28987622/starting-shiny-app-after-password-input)

Comment: @PorkChop I added to the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have two issues here:

First your confirm button value is stored here: `input$"ui1Output-confirm"` and not here: `input$confirm`

I would suggest to replace:

```
observeEvent(is.null(input$confirm), {
  Logged <<- F
})
```

By:

```
observeEvent(input$"ui1Output-confirm", {
    Logged <<- T
})
```

Then your observe function does not contain any reference to the button so it is not executed when the user clicks on it. I don't have a proper solution for this but a simple hack would be to add:

```
tmp <- input$"ui1Output-confirm"
```

at the begining of the observe section:

```
observe({
    tmp <- input$"ui1Output-confirm"

    if (Logged == FALSE) {
        output$page <- renderUI({ 
            ui1Output('ui1Output') 
        })
        output$lsuId <- renderText({ input$lsuId })
    }
    if (Logged == TRUE) 
    {
         output$page <- renderUI({ ui2 })
    }
})
```

Comment: Thanks. Would you articulate why once I fixed the reference to the button using `ui1Ouput-confirm` it still does not work? Also, I don't understand the role of your last line of code. I thought once `observeEvent` is invalidate, what is inside would be executed...and if it does, and `Logged` becomes `TRUE` then the page should switch to the second one (i.e., logging-in).

Comment: Your observeEvent was putting Login to False so I did not understand what you wanted to achieve, it is why I changed it.

For the observe element, it does not detect the Logged change, I have some ideas why but I am really not sure so it would be better if someone with more knowledge answers this question.

Comment: Ok I fixed the code in the original question. What I didn't understand was the reason why you added an additional `if`, since I thought the conditional statement was embedded in `observeEvent` already. I'm still not sure how to use `tmp<- input$A"ui1Output-confirm`.

Comment: You are right my if statement is useless, I edited my first post.

I also show you were I used the tmp variable. You need to use this trick because, Logged is a standard variable so shiny does not monitor its value.

Comment: Thanks, also you don't need to assign `input$"ui1Output-confirm"` to an object.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution. It is not perfect but it is simple.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
        conditionalPanel(
          condition = "input.password != 'password'",  
          textInput("password", "Password:", value = "Type the password here")
        ), 
        conditionalPanel(
          condition = "input.password == 'password'",  
          fluidRow(
               column(2,
                 textInput("Green", "Green:", value = "24716"), 
                 textInput("Blue", "Blue:", value = "24700")
               )
          )
        ),  
        plotOutput(outputId = "distPlot")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
    if (input$password!="password") return(0)
    plot(c(1,2,3),c(1,2,3))
  })
}

app=shinyApp(ui, server)
```