# R shiny dashboard: generate full UI from server

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

The first MWE below generates an empty Shiny dashboard application:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

header <- dashboardHeader()
sidebar <- dashboardSidebar()
body <- dashboardBody()

ui1 <- dashboardPage(header, sidebar, body)

server <- function(input, output){}

shinyApp(ui = ui1, server = server)
```

I'm trying to generate the same UI page but dynamically from the server side, as done in the second example below where the second page is displayed only when the correct password is written. It works, however the page design is gone:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

# UI1 ####
ui1 <- fluidPage(
  textInput('password', label = 'Say hello')
)

# UI2 ####
header <- dashboardHeader()
sidebar <- dashboardSidebar()
body <- dashboardBody()
ui2 <- dashboardPage(header, sidebar, body)

# Server ####
server <- function(input, output){
  status <- reactiveValues(logged = F)

  observeEvent(input$password,{
    if(input$password == 'hello'){
      status$logged <- T
    }
  })

  output$uipage <- renderUI({
    if(status$logged){
      ui2
    } else {
      ui1
    }
  })
}

# UI ####
ui <- uiOutput("uipage")

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Any idea how to solve this behaviour?

Comment: You are passing `ui = ui`, you want to pass `ui1` `shinyApp(ui = ui1, server = server)`

Comment: Indeed, but in my full code I'm trying to dynamically switch between ui1 and ui2 so I cannot pass ui1 directly.

Comment: If you can show in the code how you tried switching, then probably I can give some inputs

Comment: I updated the question with an extended version of the MWE including the reactive switching

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have 2 ui's (as far as I understand), but you can change part of it. For instance, the dashboard body. I hope this solutions works. If you are trying to have a login page, you probably would like to look at [this](https://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/authentication-and-database.html) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38558198/how-to-create-a-login-page-in-shiny?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

# Ui ####
header <- dashboardHeader()
sidebar <- dashboardSidebar()
body <- dashboardBody(uiOutput("uipage"))
ui <- dashboardPage(header, sidebar, body)

# Server ####
server <- function(input, output) {
    output$uipage <- renderUI({
        fluidPage(
            textInput('password', label = 'hello')
        )
    })

    observeEvent(input$password,{
        if(input$password == 'hello'){
            output$uipage <- renderUI({
                fluidPage(
                selectInput('enter', label = 'Say hello',choices = c("hello","world"))
                )
            })
        }
    })
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```