# Print information into shiny-server log

Tags: r, logging, shiny, shiny-server

Is there a way to include/print information into a shiny-server log file?

I am working with a shiny app which includes an user login and if my app crashes I would like to know what user caused this crash.

I tried to include this into my `server.R`:

```
#PRINT FOR LOG FILE------------
cat(paste0("Username: ",userdata$name, "\n"))
cat(paste0("Datum: ",Sys.time(), "\n"))
```

But it doesn't work.
Any ideas?

Comment: `message(...)` is the only thing that worked for me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, assuming you're using my answer here for the [password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28987622/starting-shiny-app-after-password-input/28997605#28997605)

```
  observe({
    if (USER$Logged == FALSE) {

      output$page <- renderUI({
        div(class="outer",do.call(bootstrapPage,c("",ui1())))
      })
    }
    if (USER$Logged == TRUE) {
      output$page <- renderUI({
        div(class="outer",do.call(navbarPage,c(inverse=TRUE,title = "Contratulations you got in!",ui2())))
      })
      cat(paste0("Username: ",input$userName, "\n"))
      cat(paste0("Datum: ",Sys.time(), "\n"))
      print(ui)
    }
  })
```

Comment: Actually, this is what I am doing right now: `observe({
    if (USER$Logged == TRUE) { cat(paste0(...)) } })`. userdata ist non reactive USER$Logger is however.

Answer (score 12):

Add `file=stderr()` parameter to your `cat`:

```
cat(file=stderr(), paste0("Username: ",userdata$name, "\n"))
cat(file=stderr(), paste0("Datum: ",Sys.time(), "\n"))
```

As noted in [this article](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/debugging.html):

> A note about `stderr()`: in most cases `cat("my output")` (i.e. printing
>   to standard out) will work correctly, but in others (e.g. inside a
>   `renderPrint`, which uses `capture.output` to redirect output), it won’t,
>   so we recommend always sending trace output to `stderr()`.