# How to add simple analytics logging to R Shiny app?

Tags: r, shiny

I have an `app.r` running on a Shiny Server.

I've added this code to write to the log file, as answered at https://stackoverflow.com/a/54778579/10276092

```
cat(file=stderr(), paste0("\nStarting application: ", Sys.time(), "\n"))
```

This code is placed at the top of the UI code (for initialization), as well as in the middle of the UI display code.

However, the code only writes to the log file in `/var/log/shiny-server/[appname]-shiny-[date]-[time]-[stamp].log` when the R Shiny server re-initializes the app, like after editing `app.r`.

Is there a way to log every time the Shiny Page is opened by different users?

Comment: Try placing that code in your `server()` function rather than as a global statement.

Comment: Thank you! This is what I needed to do.