# Starting Shiny app after password input with md5 in Shiny Server

Tags: shiny, shiny-server

I know that in Shiny Server Pro there is a function of password control, but I'm working just with Shiny Server with the function passwordInput(), which is like textInput() and I know that the package digest can be used to encrypt a password, I found some apps that works perfect with md5 in rstudio like this exellent example:
https://gist.github.com/withr/9001831
but when I put the code in my shinyserver folder to share it I have this error: 
An error has occurred The application failed to start. The application exited during initialization.

Also working whihtout md5 I found this example:
[Starting Shiny app after password input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28987622/starting-shiny-app-after-password-input)
again it works perfect in rstudio but when I put the code in my shinyserver folder to share it I have this error: 
ERROR: An error has occurred. Check your logs or contact the app author for clarification.

I have other apps working, but just with passwordinput and conditionals but that's not secure and with that I can't do a good control of who is loggin, I think this it not a problem from the packages, because I have the same packages in my default library and in the shiny library.

I think the problem maybe is in the privilegies because in the var/log/shiny-server
I have this
-su: línea 0: cd: /srv/shiny-server/RIESGOS/SUSPENDIDOS_F: Permiso denegado

SUSPENDIDOS_F is the name of the folder that contains the codes
For other apps the logs are ok

Please help me to solve this, I need and app like this examples working in Shiny Server.