# shiny R: making a tab to be accessible after loginng in

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server, shinydashboard

I am building a shiny app that allows users to look around everything in the web except for one tab, which is accessible to the administrator only (who knows login info).

I have found a similar post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42636849/shiny-password-causing-disconnect-when-deployed/42637827#42637827) and modified it a little bit to make the **signup** tab to be displayed only after logging in. In order to do that, I made

1. ui1 to be a login page
2. ui2 to be the shinydashboard with the signup tab to be a login page
3. ui3 to be the entire shinydashboard with login page

I made the app to start with ui2 code, where the user is directed to a login page when he clicks the sign_up tab. If the user successfully logs in, he is directed to the ui3 shinydashboard which has other information instead of the login page. Other than what's in the **signup** tab, everything is the same for ui2 and ui3.

However, when I start the app and click the "signup" tab, it displays an error saying **Error: could not find function "ui1"**

Here is what I have in the ui.R file:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyjs)
library(googleVis)
library(flexdashboard)
library(DT)
library(dimple)
library(dplyr)

ui1 <-tagList(
  div(id = "login",
  wellPanel(textInput("userName", "Username"),
            passwordInput("passwd", "Password"),
            br(),actionButton("Login", "Log in"))),
  tags$style(type="text/css", "#login {font-size:10px;   text-align: left;position:absolute;top: 40%;left: 50%;margin-top: -100px;margin-left: -150px;}")
)

ui2<- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title="S-League X Shoot!"),
  dashboardSidebar(
gaugeOutput("plt1",height='130px'),
sidebarMenu(
  menuItem("Shoot 소개", tabName = "shoot_info", icon= icon("heart", lib= "glyphicon")),
  menuItem("점수순위 및 분석", tabName = "leaderboard", icon= icon("bar-chart-o")),
  menuItem("참가신청서", tabName = "signup", icon=icon("pencil", lib= "glyphicon"),
           badgeLabel = "관리자", badgeColor = "red")
),
uiOutput("checkbox")
  ),
  dashboardBody(
tabItems(
  tabItem(tabName = "shoot_info",
          fluidRow(
            tabBox(
              id= "tabtab1", width = 12,
              tabPanel("Shoot 소개",
                       fluidRow(div(img(src="1.jpg"), img(src="2.jpg"), img(src="3.jpg"))),
                       fluidRow(div(img(src="4.jpg"), img(src="5.jpg"), img(src="6.jpg")))
              ),
              tabPanel("소아암 소개 및 후원",
                       fluidRow(tags$a(img(src="66.jpg"),href="http://www.soaam.or.kr/donation/introduction.php?PHPSESSID=80f03a3e88d2ee7137d904c22e00a75b")),
                       fluidRow(div(img(src="11.jpg"))),
                       fluidRow(div(img(src="22.png"))),
                       fluidRow(div(img(src="33.png"))),
                       fluidRow(div(img(src="44.png"))),
                       fluidRow(div(img(src="55.png")))
              ),
              tabPanel("2016년도 Shoot 활동",
                       fluidRow(div(img(src="111.jpg"))),
                       fluidRow(div(img(src="222.jpg"))),
                       fluidRow(div(img(src="333.jpg"))),
                       fluidRow(div(img(src="444.jpg"))),
                       fluidRow(div(img(src="555.jpg"))),
                       fluidRow(div(img(src="666.jpg")))
              )
            )
          )
  ),
  tabItem(tabName = "leaderboard",
          fluidRow(
            tabBox(
              id= "tabtab2", width = 12,
              tabPanel("선수별순위",
                       dataTableOutput("content"),
                       dimpleOutput("distPlot1"),
                       width=12),
              tabPanel("팀별순위",
                       uiOutput("summa2"), 
                       dimpleOutput("distPlot2"),
                       width=6),
              tabPanel("단과대별순위",
                       uiOutput("summa3"), 
                       dimpleOutput("distPlot3"),
                       width=6)
            )
          )
  ),
  tabItem(tabName = "signup",
          uiOutput("page") #This is the only difference between ui2 and ui3
  )

))
)

ui3<- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title="S-League X Shoot!"),
  dashboardSidebar(
gaugeOutput("plt1",height='130px'),
sidebarMenu(
  menuItem("Shoot 소개", tabName = "shoot_info", icon= icon("heart", lib= "glyphicon")),
  menuItem("점수순위 및 분석", tabName = "leaderboard", icon= icon("bar-chart-o")),
  menuItem("참가신청서", tabName = "signup", icon=icon("pencil", lib= "glyphicon"),
           badgeLabel = "관리자", badgeColor = "red")
),
uiOutput("checkbox")
  ),
  dashboardBody(
tabItems(
  tabItem(tabName = "shoot_info",
          fluidRow(
            tabBox(
              id= "tabtab1", width = 12,
              tabPanel("Shoot 소개",
                       fluidRow(div(img(src="1.jpg"), img(src="2.jpg"), img(src="3.jpg"))),
                       fluidRow(div(img(src="4.jpg"), img(src="5.jpg"), img(src="6.jpg")))
              ),
              tabPanel("소아암 소개 및 후원",
                       fluidRow(tags$a(img(src="66.jpg"),href="http://www.soaam.or.kr/donation/introduction.php?PHPSESSID=80f03a3e88d2ee7137d904c22e00a75b")),
                       fluidRow(div(img(src="11.jpg"))),
                       fluidRow(div(img(src="22.png"))),
                       fluidRow(div(img(src="33.png"))),
                       fluidRow(div(img(src="44.png"))),
                       fluidRow(div(img(src="55.png")))
              ),
              tabPanel("2016년도 Shoot 활동",
                       fluidRow(div(img(src="111.jpg"))),
                       fluidRow(div(img(src="222.jpg"))),
                       fluidRow(div(img(src="333.jpg"))),
                       fluidRow(div(img(src="444.jpg"))),
                       fluidRow(div(img(src="555.jpg"))),
                       fluidRow(div(img(src="666.jpg")))
              )
            )
          )
  ),
  tabItem(tabName = "leaderboard",
          fluidRow(
            tabBox(
              id= "tabtab2", width = 12,
              tabPanel("선수별순위",
                       dataTableOutput("content"),
                       dimpleOutput("distPlot1"),
                       width=12),
              tabPanel("팀별순위",
                       uiOutput("summa2"), 
                       dimpleOutput("distPlot2"),
                       width=6),
              tabPanel("단과대별순위",
                       uiOutput("summa3"), 
                       dimpleOutput("distPlot3"),
                       width=6)
            )
          )
  ),
  tabItem(tabName = "signup",
          fluidRow(
            tabBox(
              id= "tabset1", width = 12,
              tabPanel("참가신청서", textInput("name",  "이름"),
                       radioButtons("gender", "성별", list("남자","여자")),
                       selectInput("college", "대학",
                                   choices = list("간호대학", "경영대학",
                                                  "공과대학", "농업생명과학대학",
                                                  "미술대학", "법과대학",
                                                  "사범대학", "사회과학대학",
                                                  "수의과대학", "생활과학대학",
                                                  "약학대학", "음악대학",
                                                  "인문대학", "의과대학",
                                                  "자연과학대학", "기타"),
                                   selected = 1),
                       selectInput("team", "교내 소속축구팀",
                                   choices = list("싸커21", "아르마다",
                                                  "에코플러스", "아크로",
                                                  "P.O.S", "공대",
                                                  "자연대", "관악사",
                                                  "농대축구부 휘모리", "지오싸카스",
                                                  "새츠", "샥스",
                                                  "FC SEES", "Cells United",
                                                  "프리템포", "남풍",
                                                  "없음")),
                       textInput("score", "점수"),
                       actionButton("click_counter","Submit"), width=12),
              tabPanel("참가자 삭제", textInput("delete_name", "삭제할 참가자 이름을 아래 박스에 기입한 뒤, 삭제 버튼을 눌러주세요."),
                       actionButton("delete_button","삭제"), 
                       h4("주의사항: 동명이인이 있을시, 모두가 삭제되므로 삭제하지 않고자 하는 참가자의 정보를 다시 '참가신청서' tab에서 기입해줘야 함."),width=12)
            )
          ),
          fluidRow(
            box(dataTableOutput("nText"), width=12)
          )
  )

))
)
```

This is what I have in the server.R file:

```
server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

  Logged = FALSE;
  my_username <- "test"
  my_password <- "test"

  USER <- reactiveValues(Logged = Logged)



  observe({ 
if (USER$Logged == FALSE) {
  if (!is.null(input$Login)) {
    if (input$Login > 0) {
      Username <- isolate(input$userName)
      Password <- isolate(input$passwd)
      Id.username <- which(my_username == Username)
      Id.password <- which(my_password == Password)
      if (length(Id.username) > 0 & length(Id.password) > 0) {
        if (Id.username == Id.password) {
          USER$Logged <- TRUE
        } 
      }
    } 
  }
}    
  })

  output$page <- renderUI({
if (USER$Logged == FALSE){
  output$page <- renderUI({
    div(class="outer",do.call(bootstrapPage,c("",ui1())))
  })
}
if (USER$Logged == TRUE)
  ui3
  })
})

shinyApp(ui = ui2, server = server)
```

Comment: Please add all your libs you're using in the code!

Comment: @PorkChop Oops, I have just added libs in the code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is an interesting technique, and once I got it working it was not that hard to fix, and add the functionality you need. Here is the code:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(ShinyDash)
library(rcdimple)

ui1 <-tagList(
  div(id = "login",
      wellPanel(textInput("userName", "Username"),
                passwordInput("passwd", "Password"),
                br(),actionButton("Login", "Log in"))),
  tags$style(type="text/css", "#login {font-size:10px;   text-align: left;position:absolute;top: 40%;left: 50%;margin-top: -100px;margin-left: -150px;}")
)

ui33 <-tagList(
  wellPanel("Admin-참가신청서", textInput("name",  "이름"),
                     radioButtons("gender", "성별", list("남자","여자")),
                     selectInput("college", "대학",
                                 choices = list("간호대학", "경영대학",
                                                "공과대학", "농업생명과학대학",
                                                "미술대학", "법과대학",
                                                "사범대학", "사회과학대학",
                                                "수의과대학", "생활과학대학",
                                                "약학대학", "음악대학",
                                                "인문대학", "의과대학",
                                                "자연과학대학", "기타"),
                                 selected = 1),
                     selectInput("team", "교내 소속축구팀",
                                 choices = list("싸커21", "아르마다",
                                                "에코플러스", "아크로",
                                                "P.O.S", "공대",
                                                "자연대", "관악사",
                                                "농대축구부 휘모리", "지오싸카스",
                                                "새츠", "샥스",
                                                "FC SEES", "Cells United",
                                                "프리템포", "남풍",
                                                "없음")),
                     textInput("score", "점수"),
                     actionButton("click_counter","Submit"), width=12),
            tabPanel("참가자 삭제", textInput("delete_name", "삭제할 참가자 이름을 아래 박스에 기입한 뒤, 삭제 버튼을 눌러주세요."),
                     actionButton("delete_button","삭제"), 
                     h4("주의사항: 동명이인이 있을시, 모두가 삭제되므로 삭제하지 않고자 하는 참가자의 정보를 다시 '참가신청서' tab에서 기입해줘야 함."),width=12)
          )



ui2<- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title="S-League X Shoot!"),
  dashboardSidebar(
    gaugeOutput("plt1",height='130px'),
    sidebarMenu(
      menuItem("Shoot 소개", tabName = "shoot_info", icon= icon("heart", lib= "glyphicon")),
      menuItem("점수순위 및 분석", tabName = "leaderboard", icon= icon("bar-chart-o")),
      menuItem("참가신청서", tabName = "signup", icon=icon("pencil", lib= "glyphicon"),
               badgeLabel = "관리자", badgeColor = "red")
    ),
    uiOutput("checkbox")
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    tabItems(
      tabItem(tabName = "shoot_info",
              fluidRow(
                tabBox(
                  id= "tabtab1", width = 12,
                  tabPanel("Shoot 소개",
                           fluidRow(div(img(src="1.jpg"), img(src="2.jpg"), img(src="3.jpg"))),
                           fluidRow(div(img(src="4.jpg"), img(src="5.jpg"), img(src="6.jpg")))
                  ),
                  tabPanel("소아암 소개 및 후원",
                           fluidRow(tags$a(img(src="66.jpg"),href="http://www.soaam.or.kr/donation/introduction.php?PHPSESSID=80f03a3e88d2ee7137d904c22e00a75b")),
                           fluidRow(div(img(src="11.jpg"))),
                           fluidRow(div(img(src="22.png"))),
                           fluidRow(div(img(src="33.png"))),
                           fluidRow(div(img(src="44.png"))),
                           fluidRow(div(img(src="55.png")))
                  ),
                  tabPanel("2016년도 Shoot 활동",
                           fluidRow(div(img(src="111.jpg"))),
                           fluidRow(div(img(src="222.jpg"))),
                           fluidRow(div(img(src="333.jpg"))),
                           fluidRow(div(img(src="444.jpg"))),
                           fluidRow(div(img(src="555.jpg"))),
                           fluidRow(div(img(src="666.jpg")))
                  )
                )
              )
      ),
      tabItem(tabName = "leaderboard",
              fluidRow(
                tabBox(
                  id= "tabtab2", width = 12,
                  tabPanel("선수별순위",
                           dataTableOutput("content"),
                           dimpleOutput("distPlot1"),
                           width=12),
                  tabPanel("팀별순위",
                           uiOutput("summa2"), 
                           dimpleOutput("distPlot2"),
                           width=6),
                  tabPanel("단과대별순위",
                           uiOutput("summa3"), 
                           dimpleOutput("distPlot3"),
                           width=6)
                )
              )
      ),
      tabItem(tabName = "signup",
              uiOutput("page") #This is the only difference between ui2 and ui3
      )

    ))
)


server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

  Logged = FALSE;
  my_username <- "test"
  my_password <- "test"

  USER <- reactiveValues(Logged = Logged)

  observe({ 
    if (USER$Logged == FALSE) {
      if (!is.null(input$Login)) {
        if (input$Login > 0) {
          Username <- isolate(input$userName)
          Password <- isolate(input$passwd)
          Id.username <- which(my_username == Username)
          Id.password <- which(my_password == Password)
          if (length(Id.username) > 0 & length(Id.password) > 0) {
            if (Id.username == Id.password) {
              USER$Logged <- TRUE
            } 
          }
        } 
      }
    }    
  })

  output$page <- renderUI({
    if (USER$Logged){
      return({  div(class="outer",do.call(bootstrapPage,c("",ui33)))  })
    } else {
      return({  div(class="outer",do.call(bootstrapPage,c("",ui1)))    })
    }
  })
})

shinyApp(ui = ui2, server = server)
```

And here is the admin login:

[image]

And here is the image after login:

[image]

In the end I only had to

- get rid of the function call (the parens) in the Shiny `output$page`  `renderUI` code block,
- cut out your tab generation input shiny and put that in a new shiny input function called `u33`.
- change the logic in `output$page` to return the appropriate shiny input function - `u1` or `u33` - depending on whether or not login had happened.

The Shiny runtime is a bit different than your typical R program. Those reactive blocks are setup and executed by special Shiny handlers that evaluate the UI functions that are needed ahead of time. So the function `ui1` actually does not exist when the reactive block is executing, which explains the error message about a missing `u1` function.

Comment: I can see the login page as you showed in the picture above, but what I want is to be able to see what's in the **signup** tab in ui3 after logging in. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Yeah, fixed that now too.

Comment: Oops I just did :) Thanks for your help!

Comment: For future reference, you will have to change the ui3 to what you want to display in the tab inside box() instead of assigning the dashboardPage to ui3.