# Combine Shiny login page with my app

Tags: r, passwords, shiny

I have read this page about creating a login page: [Starting Shiny app after password input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28987622/starting-shiny-app-after-password-input)

and try to combine the code of login page with my app.

However, I have no idea how to display multiple outputs (including tabPanel, navbarMenu, plots, tables, and some dynamic items embedded in renderUI) by modifying the part of ui:

```
ui2 <- function(){tagList(tabPanel("Test"))}
```

and the part of server:

```
if (USER$Logged == TRUE) 
{
  output$page <- renderUI({
    div(class="outer",do.call(navbarPage,c(inverse=TRUE,title = "Contratulations you got in!",ui2())))
  })
  print(ui)
}
```

I have tried

```
source("ui.R")
```

of my app,  but the images of the app cannot be found and displayed through this source function. Also, some dynamic outputs using "renderUI" in server.R cannot be displayed, because I failed to source server.R of my app within the code of login page.

Can I combine the login page with my app by the "source" function? Or do I need to combine all the code (login page and my app) together within one R script?

Comment: I will update my post in coming weeks as a lot are interested in this functionality with usernames and passwords. Anyhow, first make sure you `source(ui.r,local = T)`. Then simply put everything inside the `server`, the idea behind is simple: create 2 `ui` for login and for the app itself

Comment: @PorkChop Really appreciate it! Thanks in advanced. In fact, I've tried to source my app by modifying the part of ui like this:
ui2 <- function(){
        source("ui.R", local = T)
}

and modify the part of server like this:
if (USER$Logged == TRUE) 
{
                        output$page <- renderUI({
                                div(class="outer",ui2())
                        })
                        print(ui)
}
I put these source file and the www folder under the folder where the login app is. But, why the images are not found when I source my app?

Comment: @PorkChop Also, may I ask how to source the server.r of my app? Can I source the server.r like this:
if (USER$Logged == TRUE) 
{
  output$page <- renderUI({
    source("server.R", local = T)
    div(class="outer",ui2())
})
  print(ui)
  }?
Many thanks!

Comment: @PorkChop, Did you get a chance to update a new article you mentioned about. it will be really helpufl. Appreciate your help  I have been trying to implement the same. jessie, Did you find any solution? appreciate any direction on how to approach this issue

Comment: @user5249203 Not yet. I still have some problem about sourcing my server.R and ui.R to the password.R. If you have some idea, appreciate to discuss with you.