# R Shiny different users

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I have created an app in R shiny that is practically a dashboard for KPIs.I have written it in two files, ui.r and server.r and what I am now trying to do is to add a login page and render different dashboards for different users.For example,the manager should see one dashboard and the employees should see another one.The problem is that I do not know how to convert my solution in something that uses functions and still see the html page that I have built separately before I added the login page, in order to make the login possible.Could you help me?

```
  rm(list = ls())
library(shiny)

Logged = FALSE;
my_usernames <- c("t1","t2")
my_passwords <- c("t10", "t20")
roles<-c("adm","ang")
role<-c()


ui1 <- function(){
  tagList(
    div(id = "login",
        wellPanel(textInput("userName", "Username"),
                  passwordInput("passwd", "Password"),
                  br(),
                  actionButton("Login", "Log in")
                  )
        ),
    tags$style(type="text/css", "#login {font-size:10px;   text-align: left;position:absolute;top: 40%;left: 50%;margin-top: -100px;margin-left: -150px;}")
  )}

sts<-"primary"
stat<-"primary"
stat1<-"primary"
ui2<-function(){
  dashboardPage(
      skin = "purple",
      dashboardHeader( title = "Dashboard SC REMEMBER SECOND SRL", titleWidth = 450),
      dashboardSidebar(
        sidebarMenu(
          menuItem(
            text="KPI",
            tabName="KPI",
            icon=icon("key")
          ),
          menuItem(
            text="KRI",
            tabName="KRI",
            icon=icon("key")
          ),
          menuItem(
            text="Activitate",
            tabName="Activitate",
            icon=icon("line-chart")
          )
        )
      ),
      dashboardBody(
        tabItems(
          tabItem(tabName="KPI",

                  fluidRow(
                    h2("Indicatorii cheie de performanta ai companiei")),
                  sidebarLayout(
                    sidebarPanel(
                      selectInput("select_month1","Alegeti luna pentru care doriti sa vizualizati datele: ",c("Septembrie"="Septembrie","Octombrie"="Octombrie","Noiembrie"="Noiembrie"))                    ),
                    mainPanel(
                      fluidRow(

                        box(title="Vanzarea medie zilnica", status=sts, solidHeader=T,infoBox(" ",100,icon=icon("thumbs-up"))),
                        infoBoxOutput("vanz_med"),
                        infoBoxOutput("chelt_med"),
                        box(title="Vanzarea medie zilnica", status=sts, solidHeader=T, background = "aqua"),
                        box(title="Vanzarea medie zilnica", status="primary", solidHeader=T),
                        box(title="Vanzarea medie zilnica", status=sts, solidHeader=T),
                        valueBox(
                          htmlOutput("progress"), "Progress", icon = icon("users"), color = "purple")

                      )
                    )
                  )
          ),
          tabItem(tabName="KRI",
                  fluidRow(
                    h2("Indicatorii cheie de risc ai companiei"),
                    box(title="Vanzarea medie zilnica", status="primary", solidHeader=T),
                    box(title="Vanzarea medie zilnica", status=sts, solidHeader=T)
                  )
          ),
          tabItem(tabName="Activitate",

                  fluidRow(
                    h2("Activitatea companiei")
                  ),
                  fluidRow(
                    sidebarLayout(
                      sidebarPanel(
                        selectInput("select_month","Alegeti luna pentru care doriti sa vizualizati datele: ",c("Septembrie"="Septembrie","Octombrie"="Octombrie","Noiembrie"="Noiembrie"))                    ),
                      mainPanel(
                        tabsetPanel(type="tab",
                                    tabPanel("Date", tableOutput("date")),
                                    tabPanel("Vanzari", 
                                             fluidRow
                                             (
                                               tableOutput("vanz"),
                                               plotOutput("graf1",click = "plot_click")
                                             )
                                    ),
                                    tabPanel("Cheltuieli", 
                                             fluidRow
                                             (
                                               tableOutput("chelt"),
                                               plotOutput("graf2",click = "plot_click")
                                             )
                                    )
                        )
                      )
                    )
                  )
          )
        )
      )
    )
}

ui = (htmlOutput("page"))
server = (function(input, output,session) {

  USER <- reactiveValues(Logged = Logged)

  observe({ 
    if (USER$Logged == FALSE) {
      if (!is.null(input$Login)) {
        if (input$Login > 0) {
          Username <- isolate(input$userName)
          Password <- isolate(input$passwd)
          " Id.username <- which(my_username == Username)
          Id.password <- which(my_password == Password)"
          if ((length(Username) > 0 && length(Password) > 0)) {
            if(my_passwords[which(my_usernames==Username)]==Password)
            {
              USER$Logged <<- TRUE
              if(Username=="t1")
              {
                role<-roles[1]
              }
              else{ 
                if(Username=="t2")
                {
                  role<-roles[2]
                }
              }
            }
            else {
              USER$Logged <- FALSE
            }     
          }
          else {
            USER$Logged <- FALSE
          }     
        } 
    }
    }    
})
  observe({
    if (USER$Logged == FALSE) {

      output$page <- renderUI({
        div(class="outer",do.call(bootstrapPage,c("",ui1())))
      })
    }
    if ((USER$Logged == TRUE))
    {
      output$page <- renderUI({       
        div(class="outer",do.call(bootstrapPage,c("",ui2())))
        })

      print(ui)
    }

  })
  output$date<-renderTable({
    #date_1[,c(subset(date_1,Luna=="Septembrie"), input$select_month)]
    subset(date_1,Luna==input$select_month)
  })

  output$vanz<-renderTable({
    subset(date_1,Luna==input$select_month)[,c(1,3)]
  })
  output$chelt<-renderTable({
    subset(date_1,Luna==input$select_month)[,c(1,4)]
  })
  output$graf1<-renderPlot({
    plot(subset(date_1,Luna==input$select_month)[,c(1)],subset(date_1,Luna==input$select_month)[,c(3)], xlab="Ziua",ylab="Valoarea vanzarilor",type="l")
  })
  output$graf2<-renderPlot({
    plot(subset(date_1,Luna==input$select_month)[,c(1)],subset(date_1,Luna==input$select_month)[,c(4)], xlab="Ziua",ylab="Valoarea cheltuielilor",type="l")
  })
  output$vanz_med<-renderInfoBox({
    value<-unname(date_2[date_2[, "Luna"] == input$select_month1, 2])

    if ( value> 150)
    {
      infoBox("Vanzare medie", value, color = "blue",icon=icon("thumbs-up"))

    }
    else  if ( value> 100&&value<150)
    {
      infoBox("Vanzare medie", value, color = "yellow",icon=icon("exclamation-circle"))

    }
    else if (value< 100)
    {
      infoBox("Vanzare medie", value, color = "red", fill = TRUE,icon=icon("thumbs-down"))

    }
    else {NULL}
  })
  output$chelt_med<-renderInfoBox({
    value1<-unname(date_2[date_2[,"Luna"]==input$select_month1,3])
    if ( value1<160)
    {
      infoBox("Cheltuiala medie zilnica", value1, color = "blue",icon=icon("thumbs-up"))

    }
    else  if ( value1>= 160&&value1<170)
    {
      infoBox("Cheltuiala medie zilnica", value1, color = "yellow",icon=icon("exclamation-circle"))

    }
    else if (value1>= 170)
    {
      infoBox("Cheltuiala medie zilnica", value1,color = "red", fill=TRUE,icon=icon("thumbs-down"))

    }
    else {NULL}

  })
})

runApp(list(ui = ui, server = server))
```

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28987622/starting-shiny-app-after-password-input/28997605#28997605) is what you are looking for.

Comment: I saw this post, but I can`t use a function for ui2 or at least I do not know how to transform the code that I have written in a function.I have a simple app that has ui.r and server.r and now I need to take that code from ui.r and put in ui2, but it does not look right

Comment: So do you mean that you want the dashboard page to be displayed properly?

Comment: Yes, I want it to be shown the way I built it separately, as ui.r

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With slight modification in your code we can generate dashboard as per the role.
Have a look at the code below:

```
rm(list = ls())
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

Logged = FALSE;
my_usernames <- c("t1","t2")
my_passwords <- c("t10", "t20")
roles<-c("adm","ang")
sts<-"primary"
stat<-"primary"
stat1<-"primary"

#####Main ui function#################################################################
ui <- shinyUI( 
  dashboardPage(
    skin = "purple",
    dashboardHeader(title =  "Dashboard SC REMEMBER SECOND SRL", titleWidth = 450),
    dashboardSidebar(uiOutput("side"),width = 190),
    dashboardBody(uiOutput("page",height=1000)
    )
  )

)

#################################################################################################

######Login Page#######################################################################################
ui1 <- function(){
  tagList(
    div(id = "login",
        wellPanel(textInput("userName", "Username"),
                  passwordInput("passwd", "Password"),
                  br(),
                  actionButton("Login", "Log in")
        )
    ),
    tags$style(type="text/css", "#login {font-size:10px;   text-align: left;position:absolute;top: 40%;left: 50%;margin-top: -100px;margin-left: -150px;}")
  )}

######################################################################################################

####################################ui For managers####################################################
ui2_side=list(

  sidebarMenu(id = "tabs",

              sidebarMenu(
                menuItem(
                  text="KPI",
                  tabName="KPI",
                  icon=icon("key")
                ),
                menuItem(
                  text="KRI",
                  tabName="KRI",
                  icon=icon("key")
                ),
                menuItem(
                  text="Activitate",
                  tabName="Activitate",
                  icon=icon("line-chart")
                )
              )

  ))

ui2_main <- list(
  tabItems(
    tabItem(tabName="KPI",

            fluidRow(
              h2("Indicatorii cheie de performanta ai companiei")),
            sidebarLayout(
              sidebarPanel(
                selectInput("select_month1","Alegeti luna pentru care doriti sa vizualizati datele: ",c("Septembrie"="Septembrie","Octombrie"="Octombrie","Noiembrie"="Noiembrie"))                    ),
              mainPanel(
                fluidRow(

                  box(title="Vanzarea medie zilnica", status=sts, solidHeader=T,infoBox(" ",100,icon=icon("thumbs-up"))),
                  infoBoxOutput("vanz_med"),
                  infoBoxOutput("chelt_med"),
                  box(title="Vanzarea medie zilnica", status=sts, solidHeader=T, background = "aqua"),
                  box(title="Vanzarea medie zilnica", status="primary", solidHeader=T),
                  box(title="Vanzarea medie zilnica", status=sts, solidHeader=T),
                  valueBox(
                    htmlOutput("progress"), "Progress", icon = icon("users"), color = "purple")

                )
              )
            )
    ),
    tabItem(tabName="KRI",
            fluidRow(
              h2("Indicatorii cheie de risc ai companiei"),
              box(title="Vanzarea medie zilnica", status="primary", solidHeader=T),
              box(title="Vanzarea medie zilnica", status=sts, solidHeader=T)
            )
    ),
    tabItem(tabName="Activitate",

            fluidRow(
              h2("Activitatea companiei")
            ),
            fluidRow(
              sidebarLayout(
                sidebarPanel(
                  selectInput("select_month","Alegeti luna pentru care doriti sa vizualizati datele: ",c("Septembrie"="Septembrie","Octombrie"="Octombrie","Noiembrie"="Noiembrie"))                    ),
                mainPanel(
                  tabsetPanel(type="tab",
                              tabPanel("Date", tableOutput("date")),
                              tabPanel("Vanzari", 
                                       fluidRow
                                       (
                                         tableOutput("vanz"),
                                         plotOutput("graf1",click = "plot_click")
                                       )
                              ),
                              tabPanel("Cheltuieli", 
                                       fluidRow
                                       (
                                         tableOutput("chelt"),
                                         plotOutput("graf2",click = "plot_click")
                                       )
                              )
                  )
                )
              )
            )
    )
  )

)

###################################################################################################################


###################################ui for other users#############################################################
ui3_side=list(

  sidebarMenu(id = "tabs",

              sidebarMenu(
                menuItem(
                  text="Other Users",
                  tabName="Others",
                  icon=icon("key")
                )
              )

  ))




ui3_main <- list(
  tabItems(
    tabItem(tabName="Others",
            h2("Tab item for other users")
    )

  )
)




#################################################################################################################


##############################################server ############################################################
server = (function(input, output,session) {

  USER <- reactiveValues(Logged = Logged, role= NULL)

  observe({ 
    if (USER$Logged == FALSE) {
      if (!is.null(input$Login)) {
        if (input$Login > 0) {
          Username <- isolate(input$userName)
          Password <- isolate(input$passwd)
          " Id.username <- which(my_username == Username)
          Id.password <- which(my_password == Password)"
          if ((length(Username) > 0 && length(Password) > 0)) {
            if(my_passwords[which(my_usernames==Username)]==Password)
            {
              # browser()
              USER$Logged <<- TRUE
              if(Username=="t1")
              {
                USER$role<-roles[1]
              }
              else{ 
                if(Username=="t2")
                {
                  USER$role<-roles[2]
                }
              }
            }
            else {
              USER$Logged <- FALSE
            }     
          }
          else {
            USER$Logged <- FALSE
          }     
        } 
    }
    }    
})
  observe({
    if (USER$Logged == FALSE) {

      output$page <- renderUI({
        div(class="outer",do.call(bootstrapPage,c("",ui1())))
      })
    }
    if ((USER$Logged == TRUE)){ 
      if(USER$role == "adm"){
        output$side <- renderUI({
          ui2_side
        })
        output$page <- renderUI({
          ui2_main
        }) 
      }
      if(USER$role == "ang"){
      output$side <- renderUI({
        ui3_side
      })
      output$page <- renderUI({
        ui3_main
      })
      }
    }

  })
  output$date<-renderTable({
    #date_1[,c(subset(date_1,Luna=="Septembrie"), input$select_month)]
    subset(date_1,Luna==input$select_month)
  })

  output$vanz<-renderTable({
    subset(date_1,Luna==input$select_month)[,c(1,3)]
  })
  output$chelt<-renderTable({
    subset(date_1,Luna==input$select_month)[,c(1,4)]
  })
  output$graf1<-renderPlot({
    plot(subset(date_1,Luna==input$select_month)[,c(1)],subset(date_1,Luna==input$select_month)[,c(3)], xlab="Ziua",ylab="Valoarea vanzarilor",type="l")
  })
  output$graf2<-renderPlot({
    plot(subset(date_1,Luna==input$select_month)[,c(1)],subset(date_1,Luna==input$select_month)[,c(4)], xlab="Ziua",ylab="Valoarea cheltuielilor",type="l")
  })
  output$vanz_med<-renderInfoBox({
    value<-unname(date_2[date_2[, "Luna"] == input$select_month1, 2])

    if ( value> 150)
    {
      infoBox("Vanzare medie", value, color = "blue",icon=icon("thumbs-up"))

    }
    else  if ( value> 100&&value<150)
    {
      infoBox("Vanzare medie", value, color = "yellow",icon=icon("exclamation-circle"))

    }
    else if (value< 100)
    {
      infoBox("Vanzare medie", value, color = "red", fill = TRUE,icon=icon("thumbs-down"))

    }
    else {NULL}
  })
  output$chelt_med<-renderInfoBox({
    value1<-unname(date_2[date_2[,"Luna"]==input$select_month1,3])
    if ( value1<160)
    {
      infoBox("Cheltuiala medie zilnica", value1, color = "blue",icon=icon("thumbs-up"))

    }
    else  if ( value1>= 160&&value1<170)
    {
      infoBox("Cheltuiala medie zilnica", value1, color = "yellow",icon=icon("exclamation-circle"))

    }
    else if (value1>= 170)
    {
      infoBox("Cheltuiala medie zilnica", value1,color = "red", fill=TRUE,icon=icon("thumbs-down"))

    }
    else {NULL}

  })
})

################################################################################################################


#Run the App
runApp(list(ui = ui, server = server))
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Hello!Using your code I still get the error I got before:could not find function dashboardPage when the login is successful.

Comment: Have you added package `shinydashboard` in your code using `library(shinydashboard)`?

Comment: I had some problems with Rstudio.It works now.Thank you!