# reference to existing UI in Shiny

Tags: shiny, render

I need your help. I am creating Shiny Dashboard with different view for different users. In ui.R I have declared 3 types of UI - ui1, ui2, ui3, each for defferent role of user. I made login panel and I can recognize what i should to show current user. And here I have a problem, I don't know how to appeal to a particular UI. At the moment I have:

```
  output$page <- renderUI({div(class="outer", do.call(bootstrapPage,c("", ui3())))})

  ui <- (htmlOutput("page"))
```

Works pretty well, I'm moved to a proper UI with full functionality, but unfortunately without layout. Layout which I defined in ui3 and for sure it works, I check it in aplication where i had only one UI.
I suspect the problem is in the function do.call and bootstrapPage element. But I have no idea how to replace it. Any idea? Or does anyone have another solution to this problem?

E: I add that ui3 id defined as:

```
ui3 <- function(){...dashboard body...}
```

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46690355/5894457) helps?

Comment: Great! You helped me a lot, I managed to solve my problem. Thx