# How to create a log-in page for shiny R

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server, shiny-reactivity

Is there a simple way for me to create a log-in page for my app? I want to render a ui with multiple tabs (ie. `fluidPage(navbarPage(tabPanel("tab1", ...), tabPanel("tab2", ...),...))` *conditional* upon successful user authentication. I initiate a database connection with an `R6` object, if it fails, I print out an "error" and the user can retry entering their credentials. If the connection is successful, I'd like to render the ui (`ui2`) I specify above.

```
ui <- fluidPage(fluidRow(column(width=12, textInput('uid', label =                
                        "Enter your user id:"), passwordInput("pwd",
                        label = "Enter your password:"), actionButton("login", 
                        "Login"), uiOutput("resulting_ui"), offset = 5)))
```

Comment: I tried using `output$resulting_ui <- renderUI({ui2})`. I haven't tried this, because I'm not sure how to do it, but perhaps I could use a `conditionalPanel(condition == "!is.null(dbConn)")` But I'm not sure what the javascript code for the condition would look like.

Comment: Maybe I could do this with shinyjs?

Comment: You could hide ui elements such as the tabs with shinyjs, and the use an `observeEvent` to monitor the submission of credentials. When the user submits, simple `if(input$uid=="Joe1" & input$pwd=="Password123") { updateTabsetPanel(session, tab1)....shinyjs(show: tab1)...}'  And then use a shiny alert otherwise? 'else( shinyalert("invalid)...` Admittedly If you have a lot of users this will not be very efficient.

Comment: Also note I have no idea how secure this will be.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Starting Shiny app after password input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28987622/starting-shiny-app-after-password-input)

Comment: Please have a look at library([shinyauthr](https://github.com/paulc91/shinyauthr)). Here is an [example](https://cultureofinsight.shinyapps.io/shinyauthr/) using shinydashboard.

Answer (score 1):

If you already set up a database that can hold usernames and passwords, you can have users enter their credentials, compare them to the ones in the database, and change a value of a `reactiveVal()` based on that comparison. The value of that `reactiveVal()` will control whether you show your UI or not.

For example you can use something like this:

```
logged <- reactiveVal(value = F)

# change the value of logged() when a user enters correct credentials

output$your_ui <- renderUI({
   req(logged())
   # your ui here...
})
```

For a more elaborated example take a look here:
https://github.com/yanirmor/shiny-user-management

Answer (score 1):

[Starting Shiny app after password input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28987622/starting-shiny-app-after-password-input)
This did mostly resolve my question. I just had to make some minor changes to get it to work.