# How to authenticate the dashboard based on the LDAP credentials in RShiny

Tags: r, shiny

I am currently developing a dashboard in R. The dashboard should be authenticated based on the LDAP credentials of the user. Based on the LDAP credentials, the data should be displayed. But I tried using the normal authentication.  It works well. Is there any way of implementing conditional access to the dashboard using LDAP?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean with "normal authentication" are you using Shiny Server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The commercial versions of Shiny Server support LDAP authentication, see [this](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/214577747-Configuring-Shiny-Server-Pro-with-LDAP-or-Active-Directory).
Furthermore the open source solution [shinyproxy](https://www.shinyproxy.io/configuration/#authentication) provides LDAP support.

Comment: Is there any implemented example in R for this case?

Comment: With the above mentioned solutions, it is a matter of server configuration. Your R code isn't touched by that. If you want to create a solution directly with R code please have a look at this related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28987622/starting-shiny-app-after-password-input/). Unfortunately they aren't using LDAP.