# Microsoft autentification in shiny

Tags: azure, authentication, shiny

Good Morning,

I need to make a shiny app with sensitive data that can only be seen for people from the company, and I need to know if there is a way to hijack the Microsoft login

[Microsoft login](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pn0Zd.png)

for my app, all while hosted on an azure virtual machine.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have the enterprise license? If so, although it doesn't specifically set up for microsoft login, you may be able to do a PAM depending on how your company's security is set up. https://docs.rstudio.com/connect/admin/authentication.html

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54648843/9841389) might be of interest.