# How to convert an interactive R shiny apps webpage/output tool into a file that can be saved and shared on a desktop/network

Tags: r, shiny, shinyapps

I'm trying to keep this tool internal and a shiny apps webpage may not be private enough to display the tool. I have created a tool for my company that is meant to be private and internal. The data is very confidential, and the tool displays the data in an interactive way, allowing the user to analyze it through visualizations. I coded in R, and the output is an interactive R shiny apps tool, that becomes a shiny apps webpage. I'm looking for a way to make this tool an internal file that can be saved on a desktop and shared across a network instead of having it as a webpage with a not-as-private link. Someone mentioned to me that a .exe file could be possible. I'd appreciate any suggestions of how I should go about converting this interactive R shiny apps output into a file.

```
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: An `exe` is not really practical. Please confirm *how* they said an exe could be possible and report back, since there are several significant hurdles to overcome in order to do that. (I'm not saying it's impossible, just very very difficult.)

Comment: Further, there's no way that I know of to provide a `shiny`-app in a way that does not require either (a) some shiny-serving server, either with [shiny-server](https://www.rstudio.com/products/shiny/shiny-server/), [rstudio connect](https://www.rstudio.com/products/connect/), or [shinyapps.io](https://www.rstudio.com/products/shinyapps/); or (b) running it in an interactive R session, either with R installed locally or via [rstudio-server](https://www.rstudio.com/products/rstudio-server-pro/) (pro or free).

Comment: While there are mechanisms for embedding R into other compiled tools (e.g., Dirk's [RInside](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rinside.html), it assumes you or your company has a C++ application into which the R engine can be embedded. If you have such team members, then perhaps you can point them to Dirk's tool.

Comment: Apart from the above mentioned solutions I see two options: (1) password protect your app. Then it should be no problem to deploy it on your companies intranet. You can password protect an app even without shiny Server pro, it takes only a few work-arounds - there are already answered questions on SO. (2) Use docker https://www.bjoern-hartmann.de/post/learn-how-to-dockerize-a-shinyapp-in-7-steps/#step-5-build-the-docker-image.

Comment: @Hellwalker, thank you very much for your suggestion. I was wondering how I'd be able to password protect my app without shiny server pro? It would be great if there could be a way for me to do so without having to pay for shiny server pro. Thank You and I'd appreciate your help.

Comment: @AllenP. Here is the main question on how to add logins to a shiny dashboard without shiny server pro. I added my own solution there. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28987622/starting-shiny-app-after-password-input/56551558#56551558