# Starting flexdashboard after password control

Tags: r, authentication, shiny, shinydashboard, flexdashboard

I've built a flexdashboard and am trying to utilize password control/user authentication. I read over this [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28987622/starting-shiny-app-after-password-input) , but it seemed to have only applied to a shiny dashboard. I cannot seem to make this code work for my flexdashboard. Is it possible to create a secure password control for a flexdashboard and if so how?

Comment: The solution that you linked will not work unless it's in a `Shiny` environment. If you are rendering a `flexdashboard` to a HTML file, you could look into password protecting a HTML file.

Comment: Thanks Matt! I am doing my code in an Rmarkdown file with the following specifications towards the top.
---
title: "name"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: rows
runtime: shiny
---
Would your suggestion still be applicable in this environment? I know nothing about rendering to an html file so forgive me if the answer is obvious.