# Shiny R get access to colleagues without needing to download the data

Tags: r, database, shiny

I have developed a Shiny App that provides some plots which can be filtered and "play" around them. The thing is, I would like to:

1. Give access to some colleagues. This means that I would like the app to be private, so when someone access the link, a password is needed to enter.
2. Don't let the user manage the data. I mean, I don't want the user to download the data, so I would like the data be already "there", in a server or something like that. This part should be my responsability, to put the data available for the rest of the colleagues.

I wonder if these things are possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- For #1 Have a look at `shinymanager` package, as per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28987622/starting-shiny-app-after-password-input/28997605#28997605) example
- For #2 Save the data as a `.csv` or `.rds` in the same directory as the app, and load it on visit. You can also utilize `shinyjs::hide` and `shinyjs::show` also if you like to make the download buttons invisible