# Nginx + Shiny server + authentication method

Tags: authentication, nginx, shiny

I have a docker environment and I created a `R Shiny` and `Nginx` containers...
things work fine and i can access my apps through `https://shiny.domain.com/app1` or `https://shiny.domain.com/app2`.

these apps need to be embedded in a vuejs web project as an iframe and maybe elsewhere, and that is the problem, I can't leave it wide open...

I'm wondering how I could close shiny to public access and only allow access to it through a token or other authentication method..  would it be better to implement some auth method at nginx level?

any guidance would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ShinyManager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28987622/starting-shiny-app-after-password-input) is one option. You could also take some hints from [how it was done](https://pawamoy.github.io/posts/django-auth-server-for-shiny/) with Django. If these links break you could refer it from the [WaybackMachine](https://archive.org/web/).