# In an app with 2 different versions of shiny widget for each user speicic user may be able to set the choices of shiny widget of the other user

Tags: r, shiny, shinymanager

I have the shiny app below in which there are 2 users the `shiny`(admin) and the `shinymanager`. Depending on which credentials the user may use he sees a different `selectInput()` "Variable".

What I want to do is to give the `shiny` user the ability to set the values that the `shinymanager` will see in his "Variable" `selectInput()` with the "Choices" `selectInput()`.

```
# define some credentials
credentials <- data.frame(
  user = c("shiny", "shinymanager"), # mandatory
  password = c("azerty", "12345"), # mandatory
  start = c("2019-04-15"), # optinal (all others)
  expire = c(NA, NA),
  admin = c(FALSE, TRUE),
  comment = "Simple and secure authentification mechanism
  for single ‘Shiny’ applications.",
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)

library(shiny)
library(shinymanager)

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$h2("My secure application"),
  uiOutput("myinput"),
  uiOutput("chs"),
  actionButton("action_logout", "Logout")
  
)

# Wrap your UI with secure_app
ui <- secure_app(ui)


server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$action_logout, {
    session$reload()
  })
  # call the server part
  # check_credentials returns a function to authenticate users
  res_auth <- secure_server(
    check_credentials = check_credentials(credentials)
  )
  output$chs<-renderUI({
    if (reactiveValuesToList(res_auth)$user == "shiny") {
      selectInput("ch",
                  "Choices:",
                  choices = c("Cylinders" = "cyl",
                              "Transmission" = "am",
                              "Gears" = "gear"),selected="cyl,multiple = T)
    }
    else{
      
    }
      
  })
  output$myinput <- renderUI({
    
    if (reactiveValuesToList(res_auth)$user == "shiny") {
      # if (TRUE) {
      mychoices <- c("Cylinders" = "cyl",
                     "Transmission" = "am",
                     "Gears" = "gear")
    } else {
      mychoices <- input$ch
    }
    
    selectInput("variable",
                "Variable:",
                choices = mychoices)
  })
  
  
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We somehow need to save the choices made by the `shiny` user, but you would need to think about, to which point in time the choices should be saved. In the example below I just save the choices each time the `input$choices` are changed. I just use `saveRDS` and `readRDS` to save it in the working directory of the app, but you can use a subfolder or a database or whatever other options you might have.

You would also need to think about, what the `shinymanager` see if no choices have been saved so far - I left this out in the approach below.

```
# define some credentials
credentials <- data.frame(
  user = c("shiny", "shinymanager"), # mandatory
  password = c("azerty", "12345"), # mandatory
  start = c("2019-04-15"), # optinal (all others)
  expire = c(NA, NA),
  admin = c(FALSE, TRUE),
  comment = "Simple and secure authentification mechanism
  for single ‘Shiny’ applications.",
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)

library(shiny)
library(shinymanager)

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$h2("My secure application"),
  uiOutput("myinput"),
  uiOutput("chs"),
  actionButton("action_logout", "Logout")
  
)

# Wrap your UI with secure_app
ui <- secure_app(ui)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  # call the server part
  # check_credentials returns a function to authenticate users
  res_auth <- secure_server(
    check_credentials = check_credentials(credentials)
  )
  
  observeEvent(input$action_logout, {
    session$reload()
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$choices, {
    if (reactiveValuesToList(res_auth)$user == "shiny") {
      print("Lets save")
      print(getwd())
      saveRDS(input$choices, file = "save_choices.rds")
    }
  })
  
  output$chs <- renderUI({
    if (reactiveValuesToList(res_auth)$user == "shiny") {
      selectInput("choices",
                  "Choices:",
                  choices = c("Cylinders" = "cyl",
                              "Transmission" = "am",
                              "Gears" = "gear"),
                  multiple = TRUE)
    }
  })
  
  output$myinput <- renderUI({
    
    if (reactiveValuesToList(res_auth)$user == "shiny") {
      
      mychoices <- c("Cylinders" = "cyl",
                     "Transmission" = "am",
                     "Gears" = "gear")
    } else if (file.exists("save_choices.RDS")) {
      
      mychoices <- readRDS(file = "save_choices.rds")
      
    } else {
      
      mychoices <- NULL
      
    } 
  
  selectInput("variable",
              "Variable:",
              choices = mychoices)
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: the choices made in shiny mode should after log in in the shinymanager mode to de displayed in the Variable selectInput(). I do not see them there

Comment: @firmo23: Please check again, there was a missing closing bracket. It should work.

Comment: Could you take a look at this shiny issue? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71023022/create-a-dynamic-table-on-shiny-app-based-on-shiny-widget-and-row-selection-of-a

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73099597/update-a-dataset-after-putting-a-new-value-in-the-dtdatatable could you take a look at this?